# Run python script from Parse Cloud Code (Background Job)

Tags: python, parse-platform

**Main.js**

```
Parse.Cloud.job("grabPrices", function(request, status) {
    // Set up to modify user data
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://xxx.parseapp.com/xxx.py',
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        }
    })
});
```

Main.js is a Parse Cloud Job that I want to run which basically accesses a python script and runs it. Is this possible? If so, what changes do I make in my code?

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you have your python code on a server somewhere else. I don't think you can have it on parse. Because even if what you posted works it would only retrieve the contents of the file, you wouldn't be able to execute it.

Comment: So any ideas on which server I can use to execute my python script

Comment: You can probably put it on a free tier at AWS, or use heroku

Comment: @FelixDumit Thanks for the comment. I just used heroku like one of the answers below and accomplished getting my python code to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by using Heroku.

My code is similar to @AlexCoren's answer, shown below:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("grabPrices", function(request, status) {
    // Set up to modify user data
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: 'https://xxx.herokuapp.com/',
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            status.success("Pricelist grabbed successfully!");
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            status.success("Oops.... something went wrong.");
        }
    })
});
```

And for heroku, I just slightly modified the `views.py` file (I just followed the tutorial 'Getting started with python', downloaded the example project and modified the `\python-getting-started\hello\views.py` file):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import urllib2
import urllib
#import requests
import json, httplib
import time
from datetime import datetime

from .models import Greeting

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
# I put my python code here so it will run at the url `https://xxx.herokuapp.com/'
```

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar in one of my apps. I hosted it on Heroku. The code looks as follows:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('MyFunction', function(request, response) {
    var someParam = request.params['SOME_PARAM'];
    var url = 'http://myapp.herokuapp.com/?param=' + someParam;
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: url,
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.headers);
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            response.success();
        }, error: function(httpResponse) {
            response.error('Uh oh!');
        }
    });
});
```

That url specifies a parameter which gets sent to my server to and then used as a parameter in my python script.

Comment: I just actually accomplished the same thing, although unfortunately i didn't get to read your answer. I appreciate it though, thank-you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Parse backend only executes javascript files (cloud code folder) or html, css and javascript files (public folders).

Even if you are able to upload a python file to one of the folders, you want be able to execute the file.

You can upload your python file to your public folder and you would have a URL for it (mysubdomain.parseapp.com/python_file.py) but if you use Parse.Cloud.httpRequest, you'll get the content of the file, the server won't execute the file.

For example, if your python file has the following code:

```
print "Hello World!"
```

The result you'll get on your httpRequest will be:

```
print "Hello World!"
```

Instead of:

```
Hello World!
```

Which is what you want.

The python file should be hosted in other server that executes python.

I hope this makes sense.
Javier.